# what does ~' imply when added as a prefix to a variable in macro

Tags: clojure

Given the macro below -

```
(defmacro defhello [fn-name body]   `(defn ~fn-name [~'name] ~body))
```

and a function defined when called as -

> (defhello greeting (str "Hello" name))

and called as

> (greeting "Joe")

, will return

`Hello Joe`

I do not understand the usage of ~' in front of the *name* parameter? What does it do? Don't quote (') and unquote (~) cancel each other? What happens when they are used together? Why not just write *name* without them?

Comment: Where did this example come from?

Comment: I wrote it. Its working as expected. However the ~' was just trial and error, so wanted to know why it works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In short, the `~` evaluates the expression in the syntax-quoted form just like it does for `~fn-name`. In this case, the expression to evaluate is `'name`, in which the result is the unqualified symbol `name`.

However, lets break this down one piece at a time.

If you only had the unqualified symbol `name`, it would be evaluated to `clojure.core/name` at runtime<sup>1</sup>. This would result in an incorrect `defn` form and cause a compiler exception.

```
(defn greeting [clojure.core/name] (str "Hello" name))
```

If you only had the quoted unqualified symbol `'name`, it would still be evaluated at runtime. The difference is that it would expand to `(quote clojure.core/name)`. Again, this would result in an incorrect `defn` form and cause a compiler exception.

```
(defn greeting [(quote clojure.core/name)] (str "Hello" name))
```

Finally, by using `~'name`, you will have the quoted form evaluated at compile-time, resulting in the unqualified symbol `name`, leaving you with a proper `defn` form.

```
(defn greeting [name] (str "Hello" name))
```

<sup>1 - This is true for this example because it assumes another `name` function does not exist.</sup>

Comment: 1) Why does it evaluate symbols to clojure.core/name ns, and not the current ns? Is this the default behavour for all symbol resolution?

Comment: It doesn't. It's evaluating the symbol `name` to `clojure.core/name` because that function already exists and is within scope. (`clojure.core` is provided by default.) Also, the single quote does not namespace qualify things, whereas the syntax-quote does.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you quote the function definition, so it will not be evaluated when the macro is defined. You use the unquote operator `~`, to evaluate name in the definition. If name were a kind of list `~@` (unquote splice) would evaluate the elements of a list without the surrounding brackets.

Answer (score 1):

The quote before *name* is used to keep the symbol from qualifying.

If you don't know what is qualifying, please refer to [Reader](http://clojure.org/reader).

In addition, you can use [macroexpand](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/macroexpand) for macro debugging.

And if you want to know more about macros, I recommend you to read [*On Lisp*](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisp.html). Maybe it's a little difficult, but that let you know how macro works.

Comment: Common Lisp macros are different from Clojure macros in subtle ways.